# RecyclerView adapter taking wrong values

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which shows two kinds of `View`s one represents an User publication and another that represents an Event publication. Both have elements in common, for example a `TextView` that shows a time stamp. So I created a `PublicationViewHolder` that takes this `TextView` time stamp into a variable and load it. My issue is that the adapter, initially, load the right values, but when I scroll down, and scroll up again, the values in the positions are changed by values from another positions. Here is the code:

```
public class PublicationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView vTimeStamp;

    public PublicationViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.vTimeStamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_publication_timestamp);
    }

    public void load(Publication publication, int i) {
        load(publication);
        try {
            if (Publication.TYPE_USER_PUBLICATION == publication.getType()) {
                load((UserPublication) publication);
            } else if (Publication.TYPE_EVENT_PUBLICATION == publication.getType()) {
                load((EventPublication) publication);
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Publication type cast fail. See PublicationViewHolder.");
        }
    }

    public void load(Publication publication) {
        vTimeStamp.setText(DateFormatter.getTimeAgo(publication.getTimeStamp()));
    }

    public void load( UserPublication publication) {
        //This method is override by UserPublicationViewHolder
    };

    public void load( EventPublication publication) {
        //This method is override by EventPublicationViewHolder
    };

}
```

Now I will make my `UserPublicationViewHolder` for users publications only.

```
public class UserPublicationViewHolder extends PublicationViewHolder {
    private  ImageView vImageView, vLikeButton, vDislikeButton, vFavButton, vEditPost, vDeletePost;
    private  TextView vText, vUsername, vLikeCount, vDislikeCount, vFavCount;
    private  PostImagesLayout vImagesContainer;
    private TagCloudLocationFriends tagsView;

    public UserPublicationViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        vImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view_publication_user);
        vText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_publication_text);

        vLikeCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_like_count);
        vFavCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_fav_count);
        vDislikeCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_dislike_count);

        vUsername = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_publication_user_name);
        vLikeButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view_like);
        vDislikeButton  = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view_dislike);
        vFavButton  = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view_fav);
        vImagesContainer = (PostImagesLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.container_post_images);

        tagsView = (TagCloudLocationFriends) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_friends_tag);

        // edit - remove icons
        vDeletePost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view_delete_post);
        vEditPost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view_edit_post);
    }


    @Override
    public void load(UserPublication publication) {
        //Load the UserPublicationViewHolder specific views.
    }
}
```

Now I will do the same but for the Event publications

```
public class EventPublicationViewHolder extends PublicationViewHolder {

    private TextView vTextViewTitle;
    private TextView vTextViewText;

    public EventPublicationViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        vTextViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_publication_event_title);
        vTextViewText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_publication_event_text);
    }

    @Override
    public void load(EventPublication publication) {
        //Load the EventPublicationViewHolder specifics views
    }
}
```

Now here is my RecyclerView adapter:

```
public class PublicationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PublicationViewHolder> {

    public static final int USER_PUBLICATION_TYPE = 1;
    public static final int EVENT_PUBLICATION_TYPE = 2;
    private List<Publication> publications = new ArrayList<Publication>();

    public List<Publication> getPublications() {
        return publications;
    }

    public void setPublications(List<Publication> publications) {
        this.publications = publications;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (publications.get(position) instanceof UserPublication) {
            return USER_PUBLICATION_TYPE;
        }
        if (publications.get(position) instanceof EventPublication) {
            return EVENT_PUBLICATION_TYPE;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown view type in PublicationAdapter");
    }

    @Override
    public PublicationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
        View v;
        switch (type) {
            case USER_PUBLICATION_TYPE:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_user_publication, viewGroup, false);
                return new UserPublicationViewHolder(v);
            case EVENT_PUBLICATION_TYPE:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_event_publication, viewGroup, false);
                return new EventPublicationViewHolder(v);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PublicationViewHolder aPublicationHolder, int i) {
        aPublicationHolder.load(publications.get(i), i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //Here I tried returning only position or 0 without luck.
        //The id is unique BTW
        return publications.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return publications.size();
    }

}
```

I don't know what can be wrong, UserPublication and EventPublication both extends from Publication. I'm not doing some request or reloading the adapter. I only load the adapter once.

**Update:**

BTW I'm using this RecyclerView inside a Fragment which is loaded in a PageAdapter which is loaded in a ViewPager that is inside a Fragment, maybe is this the issue?

**Update:**
This is the other binding code.

This is the load method of the `UserPublicationViewHolder`.

```
    @Override
    public void load(UserPublication publication) {
        PicassoHelper.publicationUser(getActivity(), publication.getUser().getAvatarUrl(),
                vImageView);
        vText.setText(publication.getText());
        vUsername.setText(publication.getUser().getName());
        boolean hasLocation = false;
        if (publication.getImages().length > 0) {
            vImagesContainer.setImages(publication.getImages());
        } else {
            vImagesContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        tagsView.setTags(new ArrayList<MinikastTag>());
        tagsView.drawTags();

        if(publication.getLocation() != null || publication.getTaggedFriends().size() > 0){
            if(publication.getLocation() != null){
                hasLocation = true;
                tagsView.add(new MinikastTag(1,"Post from ",1));
                tagsView.add(new MinikastTag(2, publication.getLocation().getName(), 2));
            }
            if(publication.getTaggedFriends().size() > 0){
                if(hasLocation)
                    tagsView.add(new MinikastTag(3," with ",1));
                else
                    tagsView.add(new MinikastTag(3,"With ",1));

                int i = 0;
                for(User aUser: publication.getTaggedFriends()){
                    MinikastTag aTag;
                    if(i == publication.getTaggedFriends().size() - 1 ) {
                        aTag = new MinikastTag(4, aUser.getName(), 3);
                        aTag.setUserID(aUser.getId());
                        aTag.setUserName(aUser.getName());
                        tagsView.add(aTag);
                    } else {
                        aTag = new MinikastTag(4, aUser.getName() + ", ", 3);
                        aTag.setUserID(aUser.getId());
                        aTag.setUserName(aUser.getName());
                        tagsView.add(aTag);
                    }
                    i = i+1;
                }
            }
        }
        tagsView.drawTags();

        // likes, dislikes, favs
        if(publication.getLikesAmount() > 0)
            vLikeCount.setText(String.valueOf(publication.getLikesAmount()));

        if(publication.getDislikesAmount() > 0)
            vDislikeCount.setText(String.valueOf(publication.getDislikesAmount()));

        if(publication.getLovesAmount() > 0)
            vFavCount.setText(String.valueOf(publication.getLovesAmount()));

        // reset buttons
        vFavButton.setPressed(false);
        vDislikeButton.setPressed(false);
        vLikeButton.setPressed(false);

        if(publication.getRelationship().equals("LOVE"))
            vFavButton.setPressed(true);
        else if (publication.getRelationship().equals("LIKE"))
            vLikeButton.setPressed(true);
        else if (publication.getRelationship().equals("DISLIKE"))
            vDislikeButton.setPressed(true);

        // edit - remove icons

        if(String.valueOf(publication.getUser().getId()).equals(StartupSharedPreferences.getProfileId())){
            vEditPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vDeletePost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            vEditPost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            vDeletePost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the load method of the EventPublicationViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void load(EventPublication publication) {
    vTimeStamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //GoTo.eventDetail(getActivity(), publication);
        }
    });
    vTextViewTitle.setText(publication.getTitle());
    vTextViewText.setText(publication.getText());
}
```

I commented some code just because I was testing, but as you can see, I only do setTexts and assing some images.

And this is how I set the adapter, LinearLayoutManager, etc. In the onViewCreated method of the fragment.

```
vRecyclerView = (FixedRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_publications);
        vSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        mFeedCallback.onScrollReady(vRecyclerView);
        mLayoutManager = buildLayoutManager();
        vRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        vRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
        mAdapter = new PublicationAdapter();
        vSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        vSwipeRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color._SWIPER_COLOR_1, R.color._SWIPER_COLOR_2,
                R.color._SWIPER_COLOR_3, R.color._SWIPER_COLOR_4);
        vRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

BTW The adapter is loaded with the dataset in a custom method that I have, called onHttpClientReady, but this doesn't seems to be the issue.

Here are some screenshots:

Top of the list when I enter in the app for first time:

[image]

Then when I come back:
[image]

BTW the like, dislike and favorite buttons, if someone did click them more than once, will display a numerical value, this values also are misplaced if they are.

**UPDATE:**
Now I know that wasn't because the nested fragments. I changed my code in the way that, now, each tab fragment is in the PageStateAdapter that is inside the ViewPager that is inside an Activity. But the issue is still there.

**UPDATE:**
I found that the getItemId method is never being executed, IDK why yet.

Comment: Check `public void load(Publication publication, int i)` - you never use i

Comment: I don't thinks so. It's true, the int i parameter is useless, my bad. But the publication instances are actually the right ones, as you can see in the onBindViewHolder method. I updated my answer, I think that the issue is coming from that side. I even tried to put all those parameters as final without luck.

Comment: if user click on like am getting response with updated likes count while set view to that position is not updated on correct view android

Comment: what is getIds method in getItemId?? how to get that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest reviewing your class hierarchy and usage.  In general, if you are doing a `type == type` kind of operation in a base class then you are defeating the purpose of the abstraction and inheritance.  Something like this would work for you:

```
public abstract class PublicationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mTimeStamp;

    public PublicationViewHolder(View itemView) {
        mTimeStamp = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id. txt_view_publication_timestamp);
    }

    public void bindViews(Publication publication) {
        mTimeStamp.setText(DateFormatter.getTimeAgo(publication.getTimeStamp()));
    }
}
```

Now your "event" or "user publications" simply derive from this class and implement the constructor and `bindViews()` method.  ***Be sure to call through to the superclass in both cases.***  Also, be sure that you set *every* view in the layout for the specific publication in your `bindViews()` methods.

In your adapter, you just need to create the correct holder based on the publication type at that position in your data set:

```
public class PublicationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private ArrayList<Publication> mPubs;

    //  Your other code here, like
    //  swapPublications(), getItemCount(), etc.
    ...

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mPubs.get(position).getType();
    }

    public PublicationViewHolder createViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int type) {
        PublicationViewHolder ret;
        View root;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        if (type == USER_PUBLICATION_TYPE) {
            root =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_holder_user_publication,
                    parent,
                    false);

            ret = new UserPubHolder(root);
        } else {
            root =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_holder_event_publication,
                    parent,
                    false);

            ret = new EventPubHolder(root);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public bindViewHolder(PublicationViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindViews(mPubs.get(position));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that my code is pretty messy, the refactor that you propose is really good, but the main problem is that, for some reason, when I scroll down with the `RecyclerView`, and go up again, the data displayed in each RecyclerView's item changes for some other data from another item of another position. I can't see how this refactor can help me with my issue. As I said in my update, I think that this issue is because the nested fragments. Do you agree?

Comment: No, it's not the nested fragments.  It's most likely the way the bind is being done.  Usually when you see this it is because the views are being recycled and the bind operation is not setting all of the views in the hierarchy to a state which matches the data.

Comment: Start your refactor small: do just the "user publications" following the pattern I outlined above.  Once you get that right you add the other publication type and verify it's all working well.

Answer (score 82):

This usually happens when you have something like "if (field != null) holder.setField(field)", without an else. The holder is recycled, this means that it will have values there, so you need to clean or replace EVERY value, if it's null you should nullit, if it's not, you should write it, ALWAYS. It's late, but, as an answer for others.

Comment: Thank you! You've made my day!)

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. I was unaware this was even a thing and now that I look at my project, this explains a lot of tiny bugs that I was not able to readily replicate. Thanks for the tip Ivan

Comment: This is it. Basically I did have an else block. I had 2 types of view, both of which share the same layouts and elements. The if block hides an element which is set to `visible` by default. The else block simply fills the element I was already showing. According to this answer I should set the element to `visible` again in the else block, despite of it already being `visible` in the XML. And it worked, everything loaded fine, even after being recycled.

Comment: Thanks this really fixed my problem

Comment: @Ivan I may have a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531900/android-how-to-fix-recyclerview-onbindviewholder  I would appreciate any thoughts and ideas  on how to fix.

Comment: If it's null, why should I null the field again? Suppose the field got a wrong value (for instance, null), if I keep it null, it will continue getting wrong value. Am I right? So, my question is: do all fields get correct values at the beginning and as the holder is recycled, are those values changed? Can someone confirm that?

Comment: @EricaOkamura the values will always change. On every recycle your view holder method will execute and change the values (if you code it, of course). So, you'll never know if a value is null or not, unless you check for it, so you might as well replace all values.

Answer (score 7):

for me setting `setHasStableIds(false)` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had same Problem with async loaded images, which had *different heights*. So with debugger you could see, that positions for recycling depends on the actual size of views.

Simple solution for me was to specify different sizes, so system knows the exact size of all items. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

For example landscape, portrait and square.

So I created separate views and used them like: (simplified)

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
  // ...
  public static class ViewHolderLandscape extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { ... }
  public static class ViewHolderPortrait  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { ... }
  public static class ViewHolderSquare    extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { ... }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {      
    return mDataset.get(position).getImageType();
  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int mLayoutId = 0;

    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            mLayoutId = R.layout.list_item_landscape;
            break;
        case 1:
            mLayoutId = R.layout.list_item_portrait;
            break;
        case 2:
            mLayoutId = R.layout.list_item_square;
            break;
    }

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(mLayoutId, parent, false);        
    ButterKnife.inject(this, v);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
  }
}
```

Finally RecycleView doesn't get confused about different/dynamic item sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The one big variable in your binding code is in your date formatting:
`DateFormatter.getTimeAgo(publication.getTimeStamp())`

Without seeing that class directly it's hard to say for sure, but it seems like, if the timestamp is immutable, but the formatter is based on the current time, then that would be consistent with the text changing when the view is rebound.

I think a bigger issue (and somewhat of an aside) is the readability of the code, which makes it hard to easily spot the problem visually. The inheritance pattern and overloads here make it hard to reason about the code and decide which path is being taken and if it's doing the right thing. Here's some napkin code (haven't built it or run it) using a more compositional approach that might be a clearer organization and make it easier to debug issues:

New helper class for common view holder code, replaces `PublicationViewHolder`:

```
public class PublicationViewHolderHelper {
    private final TextView vTimeStamp;

    public PublicationViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.vTimeStamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_publication_timestamp);
    }

    /** Binds view data common to publication types. */
    public void load(Publication publication) {
        vTimeStamp.setText(DateFormatter.getTimeAgo(publication.getTimeStamp()));
    }
}
```

`EventPublicationViewHolder` as an example (do the same thing for `UserPublicationViewHolder`):

```
public class EventPublicationViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    private final PublicationViewHolderHelper helper;

    // View fields...

    public EventPublicationViewHolder(View itemView) {
         super(itemView);
         helper = new PublicationViewHolderHelper(itemView);
         // Populated view fields...
    }

    @Override
    public void load(EventPublication publication) {
        helper.load(publication);
        //Load the EventPublicationViewHolder specifics views
    }
}
```

Notice there's no base class now in your adapter, and also no need for type checking, so there's a lot less code.

Now the adapter stays the same with the exception of the generic type and `onBindViewHolder`:

```
public class PublicationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        final Publication publication = publications.get(position);
        final int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType) {
            case USER_PUBLICATION_TYPE:
                ((UserPublicationViewHolder) viewHolder).load((UserPublication) publication);
                break;
            case EVENT_PUBLICATION_TYPE:
                ((EventPublicationViewHolder) viewHolder).load((EventPublication) publication);
                break;
            default:
                // Blow up in whatever way you choose.
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Notice it maintains a very similar pattern to your `onCreateViewHolder`, so there's not only less overall code but also more internal consistency. This certainly isn't the only way to do it, just a suggestion based on your particular use case.

Comment: Nice refactor, but the time stamp isn't the only data that I'm binding. In the `load` method of the `UserPublicationViewHolder` I bind the publication likes amount, dislikes, favorites, etc. All this fields, all this data, is completly messed around when I scroll down with the `RecyclerView`. Do you think that maybe is because the nested fragments?. When I add the fragment all the data is fine, everything looks good, then, when I scroll down and come back to the top of the Recycler, all the data is messed up.

Comment: It would be helpful then to see the other binding code. From the original question it looked as though only the one text view was being set. That may provide some hints. Also, can you post the snippet you're using to set the layout manager and adapter on the RV?