# Image look pixelated in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-layout

I am trying to make a simple `recyclerview` with image on left and text on right so i gave image width and height of 70dp both and i used png image `1000x1000` exported from illustrator using export for screens(android), but it's showing edgy tried with `512x512`   same result also tried putting different resolution in `ldpi,hdpi,mdpi,xhdp` still same result

without the `recyclerview` the problem persist

Single row screenshot 
[image]
Here's my xml code for single row

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heading_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="start"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sub_heading_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/heading_txt"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="start"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView Recycled ViewHolder Image View wrong size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283493/recyclerview-recycled-viewholder-image-view-wrong-size)

Comment: I also faced the same issue, after downloading 512 X 512 image from http://www.flaticon.com/search?word=calculator%20icon and replacing the original image everything working fine

Comment: Thanks everyone i solved by removing every other drawable folder except drawable-ldpi and it works now also i think using very large image was the problem 1000x1000 now its 282x196.