# RecyclerView wrong position set onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

At First, my RecyclerView items are ok, but on scrolling, items are shown on the wrong position for example: item 6 shown in position 67. Although onClick listener and getAdapterPosition() works good and shows correct items. WHY?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.neganet.darotabii.R;
import com.neganet.darotabii.beans.headers_Bean;
import java.util.List;
public class FSecAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FSecAdapter2.mViewHolder> {

    private static List<headers_Bean> items_t;
    private static int secNo;
    private Typeface font;
    private boolean showSoreName;
    private static Context mContext;
    private static String сolorString;

  private static String fSubjectText="";
    private static Static_Datas static_datas;
    private static QDataGetter dataGetter;

public FSecAdapter2(List<headers_Bean> t_items, Context cnt, int secNo) {
            setHasStableIds(true);

            this.mContext=cnt;
            this.items_t = t_items;
            this.static_datas=new Static_Datas(mContext);
            this.secNo=secNo;
         }

        public static class mViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener {
            private OnTitleClickListener titClickListener;

            static TextView title;
            public mViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                    this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title2);
                    this.title.setTypeface(static_datas.get_titr_1_Font());
                    this.title.setOnClickListener(this);
                    this.titClickListener=(OnTitleClickListener) FSecAdapter2.mContext;
            }
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    titClickListener.onTitleClick(v,items_t.get(getAdapterPosition()).serial+"*"+items_t.get(getAdapterPosition()).titr);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public mViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView;
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.titles_item, parent, false);
            mViewHolder mVH=new mViewHolder(itemView);
            return mVH;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(mViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final headers_Bean curHbean=this.items_t.get(position);
            try {

                holder.title.setText(static_datas.fa_Ye_Ke(curHbean.titr));
           } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items_t.size();
        }



        public interface OnTitleClickListener {
            public void onTitleClick(View v, String serial);
        }

     public void updateData(headers_Bean newHead){
         items_t.add(items_t.size(),newHead);
         notifyItemInserted(items_t.size()-1);
     }}
```

and in fragment:

```
        mAdapter = new FSecAdapter2(titList,getActivity(),secNo);
    final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    titRecycle.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    titRecycle.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    titRecycle.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: in `public void onBindViewHolder()` add `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`

Comment: @ kashyap jimuliya - Thanks a lot. it works. but is there another way to use  Recycling of  RecyclerView

Comment: Are you implementing `interface OnTitleClickListener()` in other `Activity`?

Comment: Yes. in MainActivity

Comment: I am not sure this would help, though, in my case it worked! http://stackoverflow.com/a/30301563/4035628

Answer (score 42, accepted):

in 
`public void onBindViewHolder()`

add

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Comment: in this way scrolled item changes to its initial values.

Comment: @sasan, check your `notify()` method once or share your code to understand it better.

Comment: but this makes recyclerview lag when item's are more

Comment: @SunnyBhadana you can remove this line and implement better adapter pattern by creating the view holder for each type of view. That will make the recyclerView recyclable and smooth.

Comment: Whats the purpose of a RecyclerView if you dont set the views to recycle themselves ?

Answer (score 44):

**In your adapter class override this method and replace position to getItemViewType(position)**

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: This should be the right answer as we do actually need to use recyclable feature

Comment: Why does this fix it?

Comment: This tells the recyclerview that every position is a unique type.  That disables recycling, since one type can't be recycled into another.  `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` is probably a clearer way of expressing that.  Or you can implement recycling!

Comment: holder.setIsRecyclable(false) makes recyclerview lag but this method not.

Answer (score 8):

None of the methods above worked in every situation for me and I don't want to sacrifice the recyclability. The only working solution that I found is to modify the return for **both** of these methods inside the adapter to "**position**" values:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
       return position.toLong()
}
```

The returned position will be always correct. It needs to be modified if you are using viewType.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this problem was happening because I had `setHasStableIds(true)` in one `RecyclerView.Adapter` (in fact, it was `HasStableIds = true;` since I work in Xamarin.Android).

After removing that line (`HasStableIds` is `false` by default), all positions got back to normal and I didn't need to disable recycling or to return `position` from `GetItemViewType(int position)` (which is nice because I actually use this method to choose between multiple `ViewHolder` types). Then just out of interest I tried to enable `HasStableIds` and override `long GetItemId(int position)` – it also worked well.

So my conclusion is: if for some reason you need to enable `HasStableIds`, you should override **both** `long GetItemId(int position)` and `int GetItemViewType(int position)` in your `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s subclass. If you do not have unique item IDs and/or different view types, just returning back the `position` parameter will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable how many answers here just deactivate the whole purpose of Recycler Adapter and NOBODY actually resolves it correctly.

You are completely destroying the Recycler Adapter by:

- Setting setIsRecyclable to false. It deactivates the Recycling. Resulting in high performance expence.
- Setting setHasStableIds to false. The Recycler Adapter is made to have internal dynamic IDs to recycle properly. Yes this will solve your Problem, but again it decreases performance.

And yes, I don't know ether how to resolve this correctly (I guess its done to only use the ViewHolder Objects and use the exact position as few as possible but I could't get my head around this yet) but all I see in every Stackoverflow Post are the same solutions, which are strongly advised to not do in multiple Talks from Google and the Google Employees who are around here trying to advise people.

---

### Update

I got it.
So the rules you need to follow, when you are working with ReyclerAdapter are:

- If you want to update the Data of your Adapter, ALWAYS update the source Data. That means the data you are setting in the Adapter Constructor (See [Recycler Documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview#implement-adapter) `dataSet` here for Kotlin and `localDataSet`)
- In onBinding ALWAYS read from your source Data

It is important to understand, that the Adapter manages your ViewHolders (basically the Rows you wanna show) only based on your source Data and just need to be notified to display them directly. Otherwise (if you configured your onBind right) it will display them if it gets recycled.

I'm pretty sure your Problem relies on using your `static_datas` (whatever that is) in your onBind instead of reading from `items_t`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).