# Every fourth list view item get marked by using selector instead of just the choosen one android

Tags: java, android, listview, selector, selected

Hey Guys I am working right now on a University project and have some problems which I found out randomly. Actually, I have to create an app (android) for an upcoming event where the user can see all the events in an overview and can tag his favorite ones.

I have a listview object, which is displaying all the items from a List<> 
I wanna give the opportunity that the user can tag his favorite events which shall appear in a new fragment but I have problems with the changing icon. When you tag the first item in the list, it also tags every fourth item in the list additionally. I don't know why and it would be great if you can help! :)

the selector for the Image View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bookmark_black_24dp_copy_3" />

    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bookmark_border_black_24dp_copy_3" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bookmark_black_24dp_copy_3" />
</selector>
```

the adapter including the activating function to change the icon

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<EventItem> listData;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private Context context;

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleView;
        TextView descriptionView;
        TextView authorView;
        TextView reportedDateView;
        TextView locationView;
        ImageView favorite;
    }

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, List<EventItem> listData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listData = listData;
        Collections.sort(listData);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_event_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.authorView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            holder.descriptionView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.locationView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
            holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
            holder.titleView.setText(listData.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.authorView.setText(listData.get(position).getAuthor());
            holder.descriptionView.setText(listData.get(position).getDescription());
            holder.locationView.setText(listData.get(position).getLocation());
            holder.reportedDateView.setText(getTime(position));

        holder.favorite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);

        holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(view.isSelected()) {
                System.out.println("Position: ");
                view.setSelected(false);
            }else{
                view.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    });

        return convertView;
    }

    private String getTime(int position) {

        Date start = listData.get(position).getStartTime();
        Date end = listData.get(position).getEndTime();
        String startTime = start.toString();
        String endTime = end.toString();

        return String.format("%1s%2s%3s", start.toString().substring(11, 19), " - ", end.toString().substring(11, 19));
    }
}
```

And here my Image view out of the xml file where all the other views where styled

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bookmark_icon_selector"
    android:tint="@color/colorDhdPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/bookmark"
/>
```

and here the list view in the separate XML.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_container">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_event"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/list_container"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/list_container"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/list_container"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/list_container"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution can be multiple . One way to do this is just add a boolean in your `EventItem` POJO.

```
 class EventItem{
    boolean isSelected;
}
```

Now toggle this boolean `onClick`.

```
final int pos=position;
        holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listData.get(pos).isSelected=!listData.get(posi).isSelected;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

And in `onBindViewHolder` just check for boolean.

```
if(listData.get(position).isSelected){
 holder.favorite.setSelected(true);
 }else{
 holder.favorite.setSelected(false);
}
```

Comment: first of all thanks a lot... now just a stupid question because i didnt understand what you mean with onBindViewHolder... you mean the normal view in my adapter right?

Comment: The adapter's method 'onBindViewHolder()'.. Anyway I guess problem is resolved now .. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Android recycles list items for performance purposes. It is highly recommended to reuse them if you want your ListView to scroll smoothly. So if you check once and scroll, then other views reuse these views and gets checked.

So in getView change code like this

```
holder.favorite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);
if(checkCondition){
  holder.favorite.setSelected(true);
}else{
  holder.favorite.setSelected(false);
}
holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
....
....
```

Comment: thank you !
but it is tagging the each fourth even when i dont scroll and it keeps them tagged.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182223/recyclerview-wrong-position-set-onbindviewholder) answer by
Thoriya Prahalad helps.

override this method in your adapter class.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```