# RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager change disposition of sorted item after scroll

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, scroll, android-gridlayout

I have a problem with recyclerview with inside items with string time text (08.03 , 08.09, ..., 10.51...). Initially the list of times is sort but when the user scroll the gridLayout the item lost the sorted ordination.

TimeAdapter:

```
public class TimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TimeAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Appointments> appointments;
    private Context context;
    public TextView textTime;
    Fragment fragment;
    UserViewModel viewModel;


    public TimeAdapter(Context context, List<Appointments> appointments, Fragment myfrag, UserViewModel viewModel) {
        this.appointments = appointments;
        this.context = context;
        this.fragment = myfrag;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }
    
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_time);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TimeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        //appointments = sortAppointments(appointments);
        View appView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_button_item_layout, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(appView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TimeAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
       
        Appointments app = appointments.get(position);
        TextView textView = this.textTime;
        textView.setText(app.time);

        for(Appointment singleAppointment:app.appointmentList){
            
                
            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                   
                    showConfirmationDialog(app.time);

                 }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return appointments.size();
    }
```

I have try to use a method for sorting (sortAppointments) but after scroll nothing change.

```
    public List<Appointments> sortAppointments(List<Appointments> dayAppointments) {

        Collections.sort(dayAppointments, new Comparator<Appointments>() {
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
            @Override
            public int compare(Appointments first, Appointments second) {
                try {
                    Date time_first = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm").parse(first.time);
                     Date time_second = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm").parse(second.time);
                     if(time_first != null && time_second != null) {
                         return time_first.compareTo(time_second);
                     }else{
                         return 0;
                     }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });

        return dayAppointments;
    }
}
```

My Layout

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layoutManager="GridLayoutManager"
                app:spanCount="4"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calendarView"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

and item

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_time"
        android:background="@drawable/time_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
```

For understand better the problem attach a little video:

[Video problem](https://youtu.be/c8lThqQSU2A)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Looking for similar problems I finally found the solution to my problem:
[The result of my problem was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182223/recyclerview-wrong-position-set-onbindviewholder)

Comment: Which answer in this question was a solution?