# Why RecyclerView Items appear in wrong positions?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am  using RecyclerView in my application to create a forum for the users.

But I have problem with position of item! sometimes items will show in wrong positions! and some times items sow twice and some items doesn't show!
I have diffrent views in my recyclerView and because of that I used of multiView in it.

This is my recyclerView Adapter that I am using:

```
public class chatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  private final ArrayList<ChatModel> chatArray = new ArrayList<>();
  private Context mContext;
  FragmentForum fragmentForum;

  public chatAdapter(ArrayList<ChatModel> chatArray, Context mContext, FragmentForum fragmentForum) {
    this.chatArray.addAll(chatArray);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.fragmentForum = fragmentForum;
  }


  public static class ViewHolderNoFile extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView reply;
    TextView qText;
    TextView aText;
    TextView aUserName;
    TextView qUserName;
    LinearLayout layoutAnswer;


    public ViewHolderNoFile(View v) {
      super(v);

      reply = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgReplay);
      qText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_question);
      aText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_answer);
      aUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_a_user_name);
      qUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_q_user_name);
      layoutAnswer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.answer_box_item);

    }
  }

  public static class ViewHolderQFile extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView qImage;
    ImageView reply;
    TextView qText;
    TextView aText;
    TextView aUserName;
    TextView qUserName;
    LinearLayout layoutAnswer;


    public ViewHolderQFile(View v) {
      super(v);

      qImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_question);
      reply = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgReplay);
      qText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_question);
      aText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_answer);
      qUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_q_user_name);
      aUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_a_user_name);
      layoutAnswer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.answer_box_item);

    }
  }

  public static class ViewHolderAFile extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView aImage;
    ImageView reply;
    TextView qText;
    TextView aText;
    TextView aUserName;
    TextView qUserName;
    LinearLayout layoutAnswer;


    public ViewHolderAFile(View v) {
      super(v);

      aImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_answer);
      reply = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgReplay);
      qText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_question);
      aText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_answer);
      aUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_a_user_name);
      qUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_q_user_name);
      layoutAnswer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.answer_box_item);

    }
  }

  public static class ViewHolderQAFile extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView qImage;
    ImageView aImage;
    ImageView reply;
    TextView qText;
    TextView aText;
    TextView aUserName;
    TextView qUserName;
    LinearLayout layoutAnswer;


    public ViewHolderQAFile(View v) {
      super(v);

      qImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_question);
      aImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_answer);
      reply = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgReplay);
      qText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_question);
      aText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_answer);

      aUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_a_user_name);
      qUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_q_user_name);
      layoutAnswer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.answer_box_item);

    }
  }

  public static class ViewHolderUnsent extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView unSentQuestion;
    TextView unSentReplyText;
    ImageView unSentImage;

    public ViewHolderUnsent(View v) {
      super(v);

      unSentQuestion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_unSend_question);
      unSentReplyText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_reply_unSend_question);
      unSentImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_unSend_question);
    }
  }

  public static class ViewHolderReply extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView replyPastQ;
    TextView replyPastA;
    TextView replyCurrentQ;
    TextView replyCurrentA;
    LinearLayout layoutAnswer;
    ImageView imgReplay;

    public ViewHolderReply(View v) {
      super(v);

      replyPastQ = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reply_txt_past_question);
      replyPastA = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.right_reply_txt_past_answer);
      replyCurrentQ = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reply_txt_current_question);
      replyCurrentA = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.right_reply_txt_current_answer);
      layoutAnswer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.answer_box_item);
      imgReplay = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgReplay);

    }
  }


  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    /* *****************************Handling Inline Parents**************
     * *
     * 1 for item_message_no_file
     * 2 for item_message_question_has_file
     * 3 for item_message_answer_has_file
     * 4 for item_message_q_a_has_file
     *  */
    if (chatArray.get(position).isNoFile()) {
      return 1;
    } else if (chatArray.get(position).isMineUnSend()) {
      //UnSend
      return 2;
    } else if (chatArray.get(position).isReply()) {
      //Has Reply
      return 3;
    } else if (chatArray.get(position).isqHasFile()) {
      //At this position q has file
      return 4;
    } else if (chatArray.get(position).isaHasFile()) {
      //At this position a has file
      return 5;
    } else {
      //At this position q and a have file
      return 6;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    // Create a new View

    //No File
    final View item_message_no_file = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_message_no_file, parent, false);

    //Not Send
    final View item_message_un_send = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_message_un_sent, parent, false);

    //Reply
    final View item_message_reply = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_message_reply, parent, false);

    //Question has File
    final View item_message_q_has_file = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_message_question_has_file, parent, false);

    //Answers has File
    final View item_message_a_has_file = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_message_answer_has_file, parent, false);

    //Question and Answer have file
    final View item_message_q_a_has_file = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_message_q_a_has_file, parent, false);


    if (viewType == 1) {
      return new ViewHolderNoFile(item_message_no_file);  //For item_message_no_file
    } else if (viewType == 2) {
      return new ViewHolderUnsent(item_message_un_send);  //For item_message_un_send
    } else if (viewType == 3) {
      return new ViewHolderReply(item_message_reply); //For item_message_reply
    } else if (viewType == 4) {
      return new ViewHolderQFile(item_message_q_has_file); //For item_message_q_has_file
    } else if (viewType == 5) {
      return new ViewHolderAFile(item_message_a_has_file); //For item_message_a_has_file
    } else {
      return new ViewHolderQAFile(item_message_q_a_has_file); //For item_message_q_a_has_file
    }
  }

  /**
   * add sent message to adapter
   *
   * @ArrayList<ChatModel> chatArray of messages
   */

  public void addItem(ChatModel newMessage) {

    Log.i("CHAT_ADAPTER", "CHAT ARRAY SIZE: " + this.chatArray.size());
    this.chatArray.add(newMessage);
    //notifyItemInserted(this.chatArray.size()-1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }


  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    String question;
    CourseForumModel cfm = chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel();

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {

      case 1: //For item_message_no_file

        ViewHolderNoFile vhNoFile = (ViewHolderNoFile) holder;

        //Set userName of Answer
        setUserName(vhNoFile.aUserName, cfm.getCourseForumAUserName());

        //Set userName of Question
        setUserName(vhNoFile.qUserName, cfm.getCourseForumQUserName());

        //Set Question Text
        setMessage(vhNoFile.qText, cfm.getCourseForumQuestion());

        //Set Answer Text
        setMessage(vhNoFile.aText, cfm.getCourseForumAnswer());


        vhNoFile.reply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentForum.onEvent(fragmentForum, chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumId());
          }
        });

        // check if answer text is empty get answer layout gone
        if (vhNoFile.aText.getText() == "") {
          vhNoFile.layoutAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
          vhNoFile.layoutAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        break;

      case 2: //For item_message_unSent

        ViewHolderUnsent vhUnsent = (ViewHolderUnsent) holder;

        SendChatModel unSendChat = chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getUnSendChats();

        question = unSendChat.getCourseForum().getCourseForumQuestion();

        int hasFile = unSendChat.getHasFile();

        if (unSendChat.getCourseForum().getCourseForumQuestion() != null) {
          vhUnsent.unSentQuestion.setText(question);
        } else {
          vhUnsent.unSentQuestion.setText("");
        }

        if (unSendChat.getCourseForum().getCourseForumReplyTo() > 0) {
          vhUnsent.unSentReplyText.setText(unSendChat.getCourseForum().getReplyToSummary());
        } else {
          vhUnsent.unSentReplyText.setText("");
        }

        //This UnSend Message has a file
        if (hasFile == 1) {
          String filePath = chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getUnSendChats().getFilePath();

          Picasso
            .with(mContext)
            .load(new File(filePath))
            .resize(64, 64)
            .into(vhUnsent.unSentImage);
        } else {
          vhUnsent.unSentImage.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        }

        break;

      case 3: //For item_message_Reply

        ViewHolderReply vRTReply = (ViewHolderReply) holder;

        vRTReply.replyPastQ.setText(chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getReplayedMessage().getCourseForumQuestion());
        vRTReply.replyPastA.setText(chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getReplayedMessage().getCourseForumAnswer());
        vRTReply.replyCurrentQ.setText(chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumQuestion());
        vRTReply.replyCurrentA.setText(chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumAnswer());

        vRTReply.imgReplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentForum.onEvent(fragmentForum, chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumId());
          }
        });

        // check if answer text is empty get answer layout gone
        if (chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumAnswer().equals("")) {
          vRTReply.layoutAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
          vRTReply.layoutAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        break;

      case 4: //For item_message_q_has_file

        ViewHolderQFile vhQFile = (ViewHolderQFile) holder;
        setUserName(vhQFile.qUserName, cfm.getCourseForumQUserName());
        setUserName(vhQFile.aUserName, cfm.getCourseForumAUserName());

        //Set Question Text
        setMessage(vhQFile.qText, cfm.getCourseForumQuestion());

        //Set Answer Text
        setMessage(vhQFile.aText, cfm.getCourseForumAnswer());

        loadImage(
          vhQFile.qImage,
          holder.getAdapterPosition(),
          chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumQFile()
        );

        vhQFile.qImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumQFile());

          }
        });

        vhQFile.reply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentForum.onEvent(fragmentForum, chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumId());
          }
        });
        // check if answer text is empty get answer layout gone
        if (vhQFile.aText.getText() == "") {
          vhQFile.layoutAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
          vhQFile.layoutAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        break;

      case 5: //For item_message_a_has_file


        ViewHolderAFile vhAFile = (ViewHolderAFile) holder;

        setUserName(vhAFile.qUserName, cfm.getCourseForumQUserName());
        setUserName(vhAFile.aUserName, cfm.getCourseForumAUserName());

        //Set Question Text
        setMessage(vhAFile.qText, cfm.getCourseForumQuestion());

        //Set Answer Text
        setMessage(vhAFile.aText, cfm.getCourseForumAnswer());

        loadImage(
          vhAFile.aImage,
          holder.getAdapterPosition(),
          chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumAFile()
        );

        vhAFile.aImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumAFile());

          }
        });

        vhAFile.reply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentForum.onEvent(fragmentForum, chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumId());
          }
        });

        // check if answer text is empty get answer layout gone

        if (vhAFile.aText.getText() == "") {
          vhAFile.layoutAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
          vhAFile.layoutAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        break;

      case 6: //For item_message_q_a_has_file

        ViewHolderQAFile vhQAFile = (ViewHolderQAFile) holder;

        setUserName(vhQAFile.qUserName, cfm.getCourseForumQUserName());
        setUserName(vhQAFile.aUserName, cfm.getCourseForumAUserName());

        //Set Question Text
        setMessage(vhQAFile.qText, cfm.getCourseForumQuestion());

        //Set Answer Text
        setMessage(vhQAFile.aText, cfm.getCourseForumAnswer());

        //Here Both Question and Answer have file
        loadImage(
          vhQAFile.qImage,
          holder.getAdapterPosition(),
          chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumQFile()
        );

        loadImage(
          vhQAFile.aImage,
          holder.getAdapterPosition(),
          chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumAFile()
        );

        vhQAFile.qImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumQFile());

          }
        });

        vhQAFile.aImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumAFile());

          }
        });

        vhQAFile.reply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentForum.onEvent(fragmentForum, chatArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCourseForumModel().getCourseForumId());
          }
        });

        // check if answer text is empty get answer layout gone

        if (vhQAFile.aText.getText() == "") {
          vhQAFile.layoutAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
          vhQAFile.layoutAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        break;
    }


  }


  public void update(ArrayList<ChatModel> updatedArray) {
    chatArray.clear();
    chatArray.addAll(updatedArray);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return chatArray.size();
  }

  private void setUserName(TextView textView, String name) {

    if (name.length() > 0) {
      textView.setText(name);
    }
  }

  private void setMessage(TextView textView, String text) {

    if (text.length() > 0) {
      textView.setText(text);
    }

  }

  private void loadImage(final ImageView view, int position, final int fileId) {

    FileModel fileModel = InternetService.getSingleFile(fileId);
    String imageAddress = G.DIR_APP + fileModel.getFileName() + "." + fileModel.getFileExtension();
    Picasso
      .with(mContext)
      .load(new File(imageAddress))
      .resize(64, 64)
      .into(view);

  }

  private void showDialog(int fileId) {

    FileModel fileModel = InternetService.getSingleFile(fileId);
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(G.DIR_APP + fileModel.getFileName() + "." + fileModel.getFileExtension());

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, R.style.CustomDialog);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgShow);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    Button dismissButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dissbtn);
    dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
    });

    dialog.show();
  }
}
```

And this is an image of recyclerView:

[image]

Update:

I got Log of positions in `onBindViewHolder` method Ans I scrolled from bottom to top Then I got this items in logCat 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-12-13-14-15-16-17!
Items 7-8-9-1-11 doesn't logged!

This is really Important for me. 
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: check answers given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031875/recyclerview-adapter-taking-wrong-values  i feel adding an empty check before setting fields should solve the problem ( Check answer given by Ivan).

Comment: I did it but it doesn't help me.

Comment: update your question with new code that you have changed

Comment: Code looks Ok. One thing In onCreateViewHolder() you  you are inflating all item layout for one condition . Put that code inside if/else . And for your problem maybe there is some problem with your data . Try to log  Log the details for each position in adapter .

Comment: I update it just now, I didn't understand what you said about onCreateViewHolder(). Can you tell me more ? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

RecyclerView reuses existing Views to perform better. Therefore `onBindViewHolder` gets called and the previous View is updated with the new Values and Styles. If you don't replace an existing Value with the new one you will still see the old one.

From the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) Docs.

> If the user scrolls the list, the Android Support Library brings the already-prepared view holders into view, and creates and binds new ones as necessary. It does not immediately destroy the view holders that have scrolled out of sight; they are kept available, in case the user scrolls back. However, after a certain number of view holders have been created, the Android Support Library does not create new ones. Instead, it **rebinds existing view holders** as needed by calling onBindViewHolder() for them, specifying a new position. That method **updates the view holder's contents**, but it **reuses the view** that was already created for that view holder. The method does not have to perform costly actions like building or inflating a new view.

As Amod Gokhale mentioned. In most cases wrong views appear because of if statements with missing else.

Answer (score 2):

For all your `position` which you use to retrieve your item inside `onBindViewHolder`, you should use `holder.getAdapterPosition()`.

P.S. Not related to your question. In your `onCreateViewHolder`, you are inflating all types of `View` first and then returning only the one you need based on your `viewType`. You should check the `viewType` first and then only inflate the one `View` you need.

Comment: Thankyou But I replaced position with  holder.getAdapterPosition(). But I it doesn't help.

Comment: If you log the output of getAdapterPosition() and scroll the list, do they appear serially? As in 0, 1,..., n?

Comment: I have 18 items in my current recyclerVIew. I added a log and this is output when I scrolled it from bottom to top:
17- 16 -15 -14 -13 - 12 - 3 - 2 -1 - 0

It doesn't log items 11-10-9-8-7-6-5-4 !

Comment: @Ehsan this can happen if you're logging inside your `case`, did you try logging outside `switch` statement in your `onBindViewHolder()`?

Comment: Yes , I did it at onBind and before of switch

Comment: Ah, then I'm not really sure why your log is skipping items. But if you're using holder.getAdapterPosition(), are you sure your List of ChatModel is sorted properly?

Comment: what do you mean about sorting? my list is not sorted with any thing.I just created a list that contains number of 1 to 18

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem.
I am using a viewPager and 3 fragments in it. When I open my chat fragment that contains mentioned recyclerView and scroll up and down all the items will be in wrong places! So I made a Log of the items position in `onBindViewHolder()` as  @Ahmadul Hoq  said to me. Then I found items will not go to onBind in serially!

finally I found this problem was about fragment and viewPager.Then I just used of this method to set my recyclerView again when user sweap it to watch.Like this:

```
  @Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser){
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){

      //Setting up recycler view for Chats
      LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
      rvMain.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

      mAdapter = new chatAdapter(populateCourseChats(), getActivity() , this);
      rvMain.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      scrollRecyclerToBottom(); //Scroll recyclerView to bottom
    }
  }
```

And Now everything is fine.

But I didn't find it out why this happens?!
If you know Please tell me.
Thank you.

Comment: hi i am facing the same issue, but i am using viewpager2 for this it is not working.